# Expressjs Retrieving Collections Based on Parameter

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mongoose

I am trying to loop my database collections based on a parameter request for one of my schema properties within a view. I have a `tags` property within my schema that is saved as an array. What I want to be able to do is click on one of the values saved to that array, which will render a page with collections that contain the selected tags value. I have been able to create the route, which will direct me to the individual tag that was clicked, but I receive a `tags: [xxx, xxx, xxx] has no  method .forEach`.that occurs when I call my loop within my view. Why would this be and how should I solve this?

Error message:

```
TypeError: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/views/pages/tag.ejs:15
   13| <div class="col-md-12">
   14| <h1><%= blogpost.tags %></h1>
>> 15| <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
   16| <%= blogpost.title %>
   17| <% }); %>
   18| </div>

Object { _id: 54c7bd20c58f389232000001,
 category: 'Analytics/SEO/SEM',
 content: '',
 tagline: 'yep',
 author: 'Author',
 blogUrl: 'roger',
 featureImage: '/images/event-placeholder.png',
 title: 'Roger',
 __v: 0,
 date: Tue Jan 27 2015 11:29:48 GMT-0500 (EST),
 tags: [ 'wolf', ' cow', ' monkey' ] } has no method 'forEach'
```

Here is my model:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: { type: String, unique: true },
        featureImage: String,
        blogUrl: String,
        author: String,
        tagline: String,
        category: String,
        content: String,
        tags: { type: Array, lowercase: true },
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
});

BlogPostSchema.post('init', function (post) {
    var date = new Date(post.date || Date.now() );
    post.dateString = date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

});

BlogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model("Blogpost", BlogPostSchema);



module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

Here is how I'm calling my individually selected tag within my route (Does my function use the correct parameter call method?):

```
router.route('/admin/posts/create')

    // START POST method
        .post(function(req, res) {

            console.log("New instance");
            console.log(req.body.tags);

            var blogpost = new Blogpost(); // create a new instance of a Blogpost model

            blogpost.title = req.body.title; // set the blog title
            blogpost.featureImage = req.body.featureImage; // set the blog image
            blogpost.blogUrl = blogpost.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g,"-");
            blogpost.author = req.body.author; // set the author name
            blogpost.tagline = req.body.tagline; // set the tagline
            blogpost.content = req.body.content; // set the blog content
            blogpost.category = req.body.category; // set the category
            blogpost.tags = req.body.tags.trim().split(","); // set the tags
                //Save Blog Post
                blogpost.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.redirect(303, '/'); //NEEDS TO BE CHANGED
                });

        }) // END POST method


        .get(isLoggedIn, function(req, res, blogpost) {
            res.render('pages/blogpost-create', {
              blogpost : blogpost
            });
        });

function getTagCriteria(params){
  return {
    tags: params.blogpost_tags
  };
}

router.route('/tag/:blogpost_tags')

    .get(function (req, res) {
      var tagCriteria = getTagCriteria(req.params);
      Blogpost.findOne(tagCriteria, function (err, blogpost) {
        if (err)
          res.sent(err);
        res.render('pages/tag', {
            blogpost : blogpost
        })
      })
    });
```

pages/tag view file:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1><%= blogpost.tags %></h1>
            <% blogpost.forEach(function(blogpost) { %>
                <%= blogpost.title %>
            <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your mongo query to:

```
  Blogpost.find(tagCriteria, function (err, blogpost) {
    if (err)
      res.sent(err);
    res.render('pages/tag', {
        blogpost : blogpost
    })
  })
```

NOTE: blogpost will now be an array [] instead of an object {}

Then in your jade, do the following

```
<% blogpost.forEach(function(post) { %>
   <%= post.title %>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: So I'm just trying to call all titles that have the same tag value as the one being displayed on the page. If I clicked on a tag for a post that said `wolf`, I want to see a page that displays all of the titles of posts that have a tag value of `wolf`. I changed my `.forEach` method to a loop, but now I'm only getting one post as opposed to all containing that tag.

 `<% for(var i=0; i<blogpost.title.length; i++) { %>
<a href="/tag/<%= blogpost.title[i] %>"><%= blogpost.title[i] %></a>
<% } %>
` Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: Well, the first issue is that your mongo query is calling findOne(), which returns a single document. Change your query to use the .find() method: Blogpost.find(tagCriteria,

Comment: Your second issue, is that you're loop criteria is blogpost.title.length. Title is a string, so your loop is iterating over the length of your title, which doesn't make sense. After you change findOne to find(), "blogpost" will become an array, so you can use a foreach loop.

Comment: I've modified my answer.